# Pass a command to docker vm via SSH

Tags: docker, centos, virtualbox, docker-swarm, docker-machine

> **How can I use a single command to send the instructions below into a docker virtualbox vm using ssh?**

I would like to run one single command from outside the vm so that the command can be embedded in scripts.  But all I seem able to do is to connect with the interactive console instead.

The specifics are as follows:

---

**The Available Virtual Machines:**

---

I start by getting a list of available virtual machines as follows:

```
[root@localhost ~]# docker-machine ls
NAME    ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL                         SWARM   DOCKER        ERRORS
myvm1   -        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.102:2376           v18.04.0-ce
myvm2   -        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.100:2376           v18.04.0-ce
```

---

**The Error Being Thrown:**

---

Next, I try to send a command into one of the listed VMs using a command from this tutorial as follows:

```
[root@localhost ~]# docker-machine ssh myvm1 “docker swarm init --advertise-addr tcp://192.168.99.102:2377”
sh: “docker: not found
exit status 127
```

> **Note that the command throws an error because the `docker` command cannot be found when the command is passed into the VM as an argument.**

---

**The Interactive Console Works**

---

To isolate the problem, I checked to be sure that the same command works if I log into the interactive console manually as follows:

```
[root@localhost ~]# docker-machine ssh myvm1
                        ##         .
                  ## ## ##        ==
               ## ## ## ## ##    ===
           /"""""""""""""""""\___/ ===
      ~~~ {~~ ~~~~ ~~~ ~~~~ ~~~ ~ /  ===- ~~~
           \______ o           __/
             \    \         __/
              \____\_______/
 _                 _   ____     _            _
| |__   ___   ___ | |_|___ \ __| | ___   ___| | _____ _ __
| '_ \ / _ \ / _ \| __| __) / _` |/ _ \ / __| |/ / _ \ '__|
| |_) | (_) | (_) | |_ / __/ (_| | (_) | (__|   <  __/ |
|_.__/ \___/ \___/ \__|_____\__,_|\___/ \___|_|\_\___|_|
Boot2Docker version 18.04.0-ce, build HEAD : b8a34c0 - Wed Apr 11 17:00:55 UTC 2018
Docker version 18.04.0-ce, build 3d479c0

docker@myvm1:~$ docker swarm init --advertise-addr 192.168.99.102:2377
Swarm initialized: current node (gnrj1sbx36j8lf82o9bk6yz58) is now a manager.

To add a worker to this swarm, run the following command:

    docker swarm join --token SWMTKN-1-57xhc6p7xpmeicznpfc7i6fhz9p9tdt48m5dqhqj3v4u42217g-50vj218ggzvm1shbuj3ei4brb 192.168.99.102:2377

To add a manager to this swarm, run 'docker swarm join-token manager' and follow the instructions.

docker@myvm1:~$
```

> Given that the command works when called from **INSIDE** the VM's console, **what specific steps are required in order to get the command to work when passed as an argument from outside the VM?**

The host is a CentOS 7 server, in case that affects the docker machine CLI commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command not found is `“docker` and not `docker`

Try typing or copying from here:

`docker-machine ssh myvm1 "docker swarm init --advertise-addr tcp://192.168.99.102:2377"`

I have this problem a lot of times when I copy and paste code from some sites. They normally use `“` instead of `"`.

## Curly quotes

In shell (and normally for coding) we just use regular quotes (**double quotes** `"` or **single quotes** `'`).

For writing (in Word, for example), it is common the quotes get substituted to **curly quotes**. But this type of quote is not interpreted the same way as the regular quotes (they are a different character).

`“docker ...“` is not the same as `"docker ..."`

Comment: OK, so cutting and pasting yours into Notepad++, and then cutting and pasting from Notepad++ into Putty **WORKED**.  But using Notepad++ with the other example in the OP **DID NOT WORK**.  To the naked eye, the commands look the same to me.  Can you please elaborate on why your version works?  Elaboration would make this more useful for other readers. +1 for getting something to at least work.

Comment: Sure. Thanks for the suggestion. I will explain better the problem.

Comment: The answer might be as simple as to manually re-type each quotation mark.  Perhaps due to some issue related to corruption of the hexadecimal representation of the quotation marks in the web tutorial version.

Comment: It is about the curly quotes. Just explained better :)